# Deserializing JSON using C# to return items

Tags: c#, json

I have the following:

```
{"documents":
    [{"keyPhrases":
        [
            "search results","Azure Search","fast search indexing","sophisticated search            capabilities","Build        great   search experiences","time-sensitive search          scenarios","service availability","managed      service","service               updates","index corruption","near-instantaneous responses","multiple                    languages","integrated Microsoft    natural language stack","multiple           indexes","application       changes","ranking models","great relevance","years  of          development","primary interaction       pattern","storage","Bing","data             volume","rich","suggestions","hassle of     dealing","Reliable                  throughput","website","incremental cost","complexity","faceting","traffic","mobile                  apps","business goals","users","applications","user expectations","Office"
        ],
    "id":"1"}],
   "errors":[]
}
```

I need to extract the items within the keyPhrases, but have absolutely no idea how to do it.

I have tried the following :

```
KeyPhraseResult keyPhraseResult = new KeyPhraseResult();

/// <summary>
/// Class to hold result of Key Phrases call
/// </summary>
public class KeyPhraseResult
{
    public List<string> keyPhrases { get; set; }
}

keyPhraseResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KeyPhraseResult>(content);
```

`content` contains the JSON string above.

However the keyPhraseResult returns a null value.

Could any body help me in the right direction ?

Thank you.

Comment: A typo, if I'm not mistaken. `keyPhrases` in your JSON and `KeyPhrases` in your code

Comment: "documents" is an array of objects that has a property "keyPhrases". You're missing the array level and the "documents" property.

Comment: Thanks Bas, you are correct. I was actually not aware that they needed to be exactly the same(Even though it is actually logical). I have changed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Document
{
    public List<string> keyPhrases { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Document> documents { get; set; }
    public List<object> errors { get; set; }
}
```

You should have this structure:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
```

Comment: Thank you!! This worked perfect!! I then just added the following to populate my KeyPhraseResult class with the KeyPhrases : keyPhraseResult.KeyPhrases = result.documents[0].keyPhrases; - Thanks again!!